# What is the radius of the semicircle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Diagram : a 40cm wire bent to make a closed figure that consists a rectangle and a semicircle. (Kinda like a door with a curved top)

Total perimeter of diagram / length of bent wire (rectangle + semicircle) = $40cm$, 
Total area inside of diagram / bent wire (rectangle + semicircle) = $105cm^2$.

Width of rectangle = $2x$, 
Height of rectangle = $y$, 
Area of rectangle = $(2x)(y)$ = $2xy$.

Find the radius of the semicircle.

note : no pic of diagram because can't post pictures yet

Comment: You say "Width of rectangle = 2x.  Height of rectangle= x".  I don't see any thing in problem statement that says the width must be twice the height.

Comment: The line between the semicircle and the rectangle (width of rectangle = diameter of semi circle = 2x) is not part of the bent wire.

Answer (score 0):

Let "x" be the width of the rectangle and let "y" be the height of the rectangle, in cm.  The semicircle at the top has diameter x so radius x/2.

The circumference of the semicircle is $\pi d/2= \pi x/2$ and that is the length of wire needed for that.  The rectangle requires x+ 2y cm of wire (since there no top to the rectangle so we have $x+ 2y+ \pi x/2= 40$ cm.  The area is $xy+ \pi x^2/4= 105$ square cm.  From the first equation $2y= 40- x- \pi x/2$ so $y= 20- x/2- \pi x/4$.  Putting that into the equation $x(20- x/2- \pi x/4)+ \pi x^2/4= 20x- x^2/2= 105$.  Solve the quadratic equation $x^2- 40x+ 210= 0$.

Comment: So your "x" is half of the $x$ from the OP?